# props destructuring in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component props looks like

```js
**props**
{
  banner : {
    logo: "...",
    banner: "..."
  },
  content, 
  ...
}
```

I grab this props like this

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const { 
    banner: { logo, title },
    content
  } = props; 
  ... 
  function someFunction(){
    if( banner.logo) {. // <- banner is undefined
      if(title) // <- this title works 
    }
   ... 
  }
  ... 
}
```

I tried to destructuring props object 
  and use all of these **banner, content, logo, title**

but compiler complains **banner** as undefined. 
Am I doing wrong about destructuring ?

Comment: Your banner is really undefined, because you already taken both logo and title out of it. So what's remaining ? Just undefined , so as you check if(title), same way you can check if(logo).

Comment: You have already destructured `logo` and `title`. You can access it directly, no need to access it through dot operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are destructuring objects like the following, only `logo`, `title` and `content` are unpacked.

```
  const { 
    banner: { logo, title },
    content
  } = props;
```

That's why inside `someFunction` in your question, you could just do:

```
function someFunction() {
  if (logo) {
  ...
    if (title) {
    ...
    }
  }
}
```

If you also want to use the variable `banner`, you have to do the following:

```
const { banner, content } = props;
const { logo, title } = banner;
```

Read more about [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you are not taking the banner variable from the props actually, you are taking title and logo instead.

You can do this:

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const { 
    banner,
    content
  } = props; 
  ... 
  function someFunction(){
    if( banner.logo) {
      if(banner.title)
    }
   ... 
  }
  ... 
}
```